# Backbone.js post model

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-model

I have a model which **id** is a code that must be written by the user and this code will be the primary key on the DB.

So, to create a new register I need to write the code but when i call the save() method I'm expecting one POST, but because de idAttribute has an value, I get always one PUT.

This is my model very simplified

```
Course = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: "courseCode"
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you are trying to do exactly, but [idAttribute](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-idAttribute) is meant to indicate the **name** of the field to be used for the **id** for those cases where it isn't *"id"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jack commented, you should be using [id](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-id), not [idAttribute](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute). (Unless we've misunderstood, and `courseCode` is the name of the primary key on the server; in that case, carry on.)

Whether the model is persisted using `POST` or `PUT` when you call [save()](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save) depends on the [isNew() function](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-isNew). The default implementation compares [id](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-id) to null to determine if the model has been saved yet or not. You will need to implement your own isNew function to determine whether to create or update your record. For example, you could try something like this:

```
Course = Backbone.Model.extend({
    isNew: function() {
        return !this.has('uniquePropertySetByServer');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As Jack mentioned, it sounds like your first issue might be using `idAttribute` when you should be using `id`.  That aside, your issue with PUTs can be solved two ways.

The first is to tell Backbone to use a POST instead.  One way to do this is to overrite `isNew` on your model, as Asheley Ross suggested.  Alternatively you could let Backbone use it's native `isNew` method, and simply force it to treat your model as new by deleting it's ID attribute (as the native `isNew` check is just `this.id == null`).  You can then either pass the ID in a separate attribute, or store in as a property (not an attribute) on the model and use the model's `toJSON` method to add it back in just before sending it to the server.

A second way, which will let you avoid all HTTP operations except GET and POST is to set `Backbone.emulateHTTPBackbone = true;`.  This will make Backbone use a POST instead, and just pass an extra request header `X-HTTP-Method-Override` with the actual type (eg. `PUT`).